# How does LINQ sort items by a given criteria?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose we have a `MyData` class which implements the `IComparable<MyData>` and `IComparable` interfaces. Then we have a list containing many of `MyData` elements and a LINQ query to get a sorted list.

```
public class MyData : IComparable<MyData>, IComparable
{
    ...

    public int CompareTo(MyData value)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    public int CompareTo(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return 1;

        if (value.GetType() == typeof(MyData))
        {
            MyData rightValue = (MyData)value;
            return (this.CompareTo(rightValue));
        }
        else throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a " + typeof(MyData) + ".");
    }
}

// main method
List<MyData> list = new List<MyData>();
...
var items = from item in list
            orderby item descending
            select item;
```

When LINQ sorts the elements within the `list`, does it use the implementation of `IComparable` interface in the `MyData` class?

If the answer is *yes*, is it better to encapsulate the sort criteria in the class `MyData` (by implementing the above interfaces) or specify the criteria in a LINQ query (without `MyData` that implements these interfaces)? What are the pros and cons of these two choices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) "compares keys by using the default comparer [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx)", which in turn will use your `IComparable<T>` implementation.

> If the answer is yes, is it better to encapsulate the sort criteria in the class MyData (by implementing the above interfaces) or specify the criteria in a LINQ query (without MyData that implements these interfaces)? What are the pros and cons of these two choices?

So first, the answer is yes.

Both approaches have advantages.

Implementing `IComparable<T>` suggests that the type has a natural ordering.  When this is true, I like implementing this interface.  The main pro, in terms of LINQ, is that you simplify your LINQ queries (a bit).  However, my main pro is more the suggestion of a "natural" order for that given type, which, in turn, adds to the clarity of your API.

The main pro of specifying the criteria in the LINQ query itself is flexibility.  This allows you to sort by any number of criteria - not restricting yourself to a given sort defined in the type itself.  If there isn't a "natural" sorting order for the type (ie: it's not representing something that is a "quantity" all on its own or similar), then I'd personally use this method.

Comment: +1 for “natural ordering” argument. The only thing I would like to add is that, when a type genuinely has multiple natural orderings, you could use the [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) overload which accepts an `IComparer<TKey>` as a parameter. This is most popularly used with `StringComparer`.

Comment: @enzom83 The performance difference would likely be negligible.  In both cases, `Comparer<T>.Default` is used, so the performance will likely be mainly due to the difference in perf of your comparer vs the default comparer for the specific member returned.

Answer (score 3):

The `OrderBy` extension methods take `Func<>` delegate - this is what is used to select the item used for sorting. One of the overloads takes an `IComparer` instance to use for comparisons - the ones that don't use the `Default` comparer.

Take a look at EduLinq - an educational re-implementation of LINQ by Jon Skeet to see how this is done - [here is the `OrderBy` post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/05/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26b-orderby-descending-thenby-descending.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In this case it uses [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), which uses the Default Comparer:

> This method compares keys by using the default comparer Default.
>
> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two
>   elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In
>   contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements
>   that have the same key.

It is probably important to note that were you using Linq2SQL or some other LINQ provider, this is not necessarily the case.  This only holds true because this is the IEnumerable implementation (Linq2Objects).